# How to fix derived class giving 'declaration has no storage class or type specifier' error?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, member-initialization

I am trying to initialize a base class variable in a derived class, but instead, I am given an error:

```
 "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"
```

I have been tinkering with C++ inheritance and derived classes in Visual Studio. I made the main class "`Food`" with `protected` variables and want to derive a class "`Bread`"

When trying to initialize said variables in "`Bread`," VS gives an error. I feel like this is a really simple problem that I somehow missed.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Food 
{
protected:
    string name;
    int cost;
    int calories;

public:
    Food(string name, int cost, int calories) {
    }
};

class Bread : public Food 
{
private:
    name = "";
    cost = 5;
    calories = 200;
public:

};
```

I would except the variables of `Bread` to be initialized: 
`name` as `""` (empty), `cost` as "`5`", `calories` as "`200`".

The output is instead an error:

```
"this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"
```

Comment: Without seeing how you're trying to instantiate it, it may be hard to tell. Try to post a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is an already an MRE, try compiling it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to initialize a base class variable in a derived class!

First of all, initialize the members in the base class `Food`'s constructor, which you have provided.

```
Food(std::string name, int cost, int calories)
    : name{ name }
    , cost{ cost }
    , calories{ calories }
{}
```

Then, you need to initialize the base class members in the *[constructor member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)* of the derived class `Bread`:

```
class Bread : public Food 
{
public:
    Bread()
        :Food{ "", 5, 200 }
    {}
};
```

which will initialize the `Food` members

```
name = ""
cost = 5
calories = 200
```